# how to change name of used object?

Tags: sql-server

I need to define names of used in a script objects in a such way I could later easy change them. For example:

```
left join dbo.rosk_crm_08012017_data b     on a.idclient=b.idclient
```

would be later changed to:

```
left join dbo.rosk_crm_15012017_data b     on a.idclient=b.idclient
```

I've tried local variables (which actually is not allowed for name defining):

```
DECLARE @lastName varchar(10), @firstName varchar(10);  
SET @lastName = '15012017';
SET @firstName = '08012017';  
  ....
select
...left join STUFF ( dbo.rosk_crm_08012017_data, 13, 8, @lastName)  b
on a.idclient=b.idclient
```

Comment: Synonyms or SQLCmd variables.

Comment: check out Dynamic SQL

Comment: Do you want to change existed statement or create a new one that can accept alterable tablename？

Comment: Thank you all for answers. I plan to check Synonyms and Dynamic SQL, and Nolan Shang decision works perect. Is it possible, to define a list of dates (for example: 19122016, 26122016, 01012017, 08012017) which every couples of dates would be selected as 'first_date' and 'secound_date' to perform script?

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating new statement, you can try:

```
    DECLARE @lastName varchar(10), @firstName varchar(10),@sql VARCHAR(max);  
    SET @lastName = '15012017';
    SET @firstName = '08012017';  
    SET @sql='select
    ...left join dbo.rosk_crm_'+@lastName+'_data  b on a.idclient=b.idclient'
    EXEC(@sql)
```

Comment: Nolan, that's great! Thank you!